# Android javax midi Sequencer not playing mid file

Tags: java, android, audio, midi

Hi i'm using javax midi lib with Android and it works very well handling midi messages, but when i open and try to play a midi file it does not perform any sound. I've verified all this steps:

- No exception handling the midi file.
- Previously i've got play the midi file with winamp and with a DAW.
- I've placed soundbank.gm to directory C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\lib\audio and C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_66\lib\audio
- I've got play it successfully with MediaPlayer class
- My code:

  ```
  private Sequencer playMidiFile()
  {
   try {
      Sequencer mSeqr = MidiSystem.getSequencer();

      InputStream in = getAssets().open(MIDI_FILE);
      Sequence mSeq = MidiSystem.getSequence(in);

      mSeqr.open();
      mSeqr.setSequence(mSeq);
      mSeqr.start(); //it is supposed this execution will perform the play of the file

      return mSeqr;
    } catch (MidiUnavailableException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidMidiDataException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
  }
  ```

What should i do to ear something? Thx!!

Answer (score 0):

From the java side, you have to connect to a synthesizer so you do the following -if your sequencer is tied up or you cant get the default you should check all others available in your system. Check the tutorials at oracle for further info

```
static void play(Sequence sequence)
    throws MidiUnavailableException, InvalidMidiDataException, IOException
{
      Sequencer sequencer=MidiSystem.getSequencer( );
        sequencer.open();
        Synthesizer synthesizer = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
        synthesizer.open();
        sequencer.getTransmitter().setReceiver(synthesizer.getReceiver( ));
        sequencer.setSequence(sequence);
        sequencer.addMetaEventListener(new MetaEventListener( ) {
                public void meta(MetaMessage m) {
                    if (m.getType( ) == END_OF_TRACK) {
                      System.out.println("end of track");
                      return;
                    }
                }
            });
        sequencer.start( );

}
```