# Sending notes to the built in Sonivox synth in Android M

Tags: android, midi, android-6.0-marshmallow

Now that midi API is available in Android Marshmellow, can we send events directly to the built in synth?

```
 MidiManager m = (MidiManager)getSystemService(Context.MIDI_SERVICE);
 MidiDeviceInfo[] infos = m.getDevices();
```

For me, this code returns 0 devices on a Nexus 6 running Android 6.0.1. I was expecting at least the built in Synth to be available.

I added

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.software.midi" android:required="true"/>
```

to AndroidManifest.xml, but didnt make any Gradle changes.

```
getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_MIDI)
```

is true.

Comment: This is a great question. I asked the same thing here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570453/android-javax-midi-sequencer-not-playing-mid-file?rq=1). I'm starting to get the feeling that there is no built in synth in Marshmallow :(